# Jmeter Script recording not recording

Tags: windows, jmeter

The recorded the script and it was working on windows 7 machine. But now the script is not getting executed correctly in windows 10. The result is passed but aftual executions is not taking place. Also I tried to record new script on windows 10 but the script is not getting recorded. I am using the latest jmeter version. Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Jmeter should work fine on windows 10.
 Cross check if you are able to access application (with or without proxy). If application is accessible through proxy, you need to open jmeter with proxy command.
Ensure you imported jmeter root certificate in browser.

Answer (score 0):

You need to import JMeter's self-signed certificate into your browser. The file is called `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and it's being created in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder).

Check **HTTPS recording and certificates** chapter of the above article for the exact steps of certificate installation for different browsers.

[Mozilla Firefox](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/new/) and derivatives have their own certificate storage, other browsers use Windows certificate storage, you can inspect it using [Certificate Management Tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/certmgr-exe-certificate-manager-tool)

[image]

If JMeter's certificate is not there - you will need to install it.

---

Be aware that there is an easier way of recording a JMeter test which doesn't require configuring proxies or installing certificates: [JMeter Chrome Extension](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/the-new-blazeMeter-chrome-extension-v4-easily-script-jmeter-and-selenium/), just install it, start recording and perform your scenario steps in browser